# using vba to write out xml file skipping blanks

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am using vba in excel to write out an xml file.  I am looping through and doing a replace using constants that refer to cell values in the loop.  What I can't quite get right is how to skip writing out a section when the cell is empty. I want to skip loop cells a(i, 3) and not write the line if referenced cell is blank, but I want to continue on to the next replace. See relevant code:

```
Const head = "<?xml version ""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
Const funct1 = "<Order function=""%%"" "
Const itemtype = "        <Item type=""%%"">"
Dim all
Dim xml As String, i As Long
Dim oPath As String: oPath = "C:\test\test.xml"
Dim intFF As Integer: intFF = FreeFile()
a = Range("A2:BU" & Cells(Rows.Count, 73).End(xlUp).Row)
xml = head
For i = 1 To UBound(a)
   xml = xml & vbNewLine & Replace(funct1, "%%", a(i, 3))
               vbNewLine & Replace(itemtype, "%%", a(i, 31))
Next
Open oPath For Output As #intFF
Print #intFF, xml
Close #intFF

Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim int2FF As Integer: int2FF = FreeFile()
Dim sFileName As String
sFileName = "C:\test\test.xml"
Open sFileName For Input As int2FF
Do Until EOF(int2FF)
    Line Input #int2FF, sBuf
    sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close int2FF
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the character count on each loop. If the character count = 0 ( `Len(a(i, 3)  = 0)` ) then go to the next `i`. You will need to add `j` as a counter and only increment when you hop into your `XML` statement.

```
Dim j As Long: j = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(a)
    If Len(a(i, 3)) <> 0 Then
        XML = XML & vbNewLine & Replace(funct1, "%%", a(i, 3)) _
        & vbNewLine & Replace(itemtype, "%%", a(i, 31))
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next
```